# sending mail without showing mail composer box

Tags: android

Usually when we try to send mail then our device opens up all the mail client available like gmail, yahoo, etc. Is it possible to send mail without opening any mail client??. Once i click on send mail button then it should directly send the mail without prompting any mail composer box.

Comment: i just want to know that can we send mail without showing mail composer box??

Comment: yes you can do with some jar files, mail.jar,activation.jar
additionnnal.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it possible to send email in background:

use below jar files in your project:

1. activation.jar
2. additionnal.jar
3. mail.jar

add this `Mail.java` class in your package:

```
package com.abc;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;


    public Mail() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
        // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }


    public Mail(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

     public void setTo(String[] toArr){
         _to = toArr;
     }

     public void setFrom(String from){
         _from = from;
     }
     public void setSubject(String subject){
         _subject = subject;
     }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
                && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
                && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);

            // send email
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }
//  static {   
//        Security.addProvider(new com.indianic.email.JSSEProvider());   
//    }  

    // more of the getters and setters �..
}
```

---

now send mail(use below code in asyncTask): **it send mail without open any Email composer**

```
try {

                Mail m1 = new Mail("fromEmail@gmail.com", "your password");
                String[] toArr1 = new String[1];
                toArr1[0] = "toEmail@gmail.com";
                m1.setTo(toArr1);
                m1.setFrom("<EMAIL>");

                m1.setSubject("mail from Android app");
                m1.setBody("" + sendMText);
                try {
                    // m1.addAttachment(filename);
                    if (m1.send()) {

                        Log.e("sent-->", ".sent");
                    } else {

                        Log.e("not sent-->", "sent");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) { //
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("mail not sent-->", "" + e.getMessage().toString());

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: yes... its hardcoded. but you can use dynamic if you want. like save in setting or get it from web services whatever...

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar i have tried this code but its not sending email whats the reason there is no error in my app ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442745/failed-to-send-email-with-smtp-using-android?noredirect=1#comment32357626_21442745